# VPN Connection disappear

Tags: vpn

I have set up a VPN according to the instructions of my provider, but at random times the connection disappears from the VPN list in network settings. Its still there in the "edit connections" list. This usually happens after coming back from sleep mode, because thats when the connection gets canceled. Also it seems to reappear at rondom times...

Comment: I noticed this earlier today actually, but have been unable to find a testcase to reproduce it.

Comment: You should report this bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/switchboard-plug-networking (I would do it, but I am locked out of Launchpad at the moment).

Answer (score 1):

Cosing the System Settings and opening it again does the trick for me.
Definitely an annoying issue!

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem here. I import OPVN configuration files (nordvpn servers) successfully, and save them with my user and pass. I can successfully connect, but when I disconnect, that server disappears from my list of configurations. It's as if "disconnect" is also performing a "delete configuration".

Only solution so far is to re-import the config file.